# Missing Ecommerce Data View Master View is configured for Ecommerce, but no data is flowing

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

Hi! I have this notification in my Analytics for months about missing Ecommerce data, although all data is there, notification is there too. GA was tracking till 8jan2020 and after that it stopped tracking. On wordpress admin sale is going on and details are there. IS Google updated Analytics or there is some other reason. Could you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are tracking with a plugin it is likely that some its updates invalidated the tracking.

Surely there has been no Google Analytics update that can cause the problem you say.

Comment: Thanks Michele. i am using a simple google analytics code for verification. well when i am testing GA on tracking i am getting active users on my site. its working fine , Thing is that just Ecommerce and enhance ecommerce is not working properly. There is some missing data flow on Ecommerce tracking only.

Comment: i am not using any tracking plugin . just with GA tracking code i am doing .